# Laravel job runs twice when dispatched

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am trying to run a simple job within Laravel queues. The following is my Job.

```php
class SearchFromSource extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        echo time();
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```php
$job = (new SearchFromSource($this));
$this->dispatch($job);
```

The problem is that when I run `queue:listen` from the command line to run my code I see that the job has been executed twice.

Comment: What laravel version are you using? Maybe try by removing `implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue`. Also try to queue your job by using `Queue::push(new SearchFromSource($this))`.

Comment: What's your queue driver set to? It should be set in `config/queue.php` or in your `.env` file.

Comment: my driver is database

Comment: Have you tried to specify the queue name? like

$job = (new SearchFromSource($this))->onQueue('myqueue');

Comment: yes it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have multiple servers?

Comment: No the problem was in laravel routes. I found out that in my routes there was a route that caused the controller to run twice.