# Laravel 9 Job is saved on Default Queue and runs twice

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-jobs

My Job is run twice but it should run only once and take about 4 Seconds and not 200ms 2x

I dispatch a Job in my Controller. (Checked if it runs twice)
it creates a entry in my Jobs table:
[jobs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Crg.png)
I used artisan queue listen and queue work both didnt work
Job runs twice.
[job runs twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3UFA.png)
On a different System it takes about 4 Seconds to complete.

I dont know why it gets done once in 240ms and runs again and fails in 206ms.

Job is using imagick and Code doesnt throw errors if i dont use it in a Job.

optimize and cache cleared ran queue commands again.
When i use the laravel command to only run one job it returns this but doesnt seem to do what it should do.
[Job runs once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIPPP.png)

[Laravel job runs twice when dispatched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452609/laravel-job-runs-twice-when-dispatched) this is not my problem my Controller does not run it twice.